# Flutter Convert String Variable to Integer

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert a String variable, to Integer in a stateless Widget.

Here's my code:

```
final String bmiresult;

Text(
                      bmiresult,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: bmiresult > 30 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                        fontSize: 40.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
```

It says `The operator > isn't defined for type of String.`

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use int.parse, cf [doc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/int/parse.html)

```dart
final String bmiresult;
.
Text(
  bmiresult,
  style: TextStyle(
  color: int.parse(bmiresult) > 30 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
  fontSize: 40.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
```

Comment: Thank you @h1b9b . It work. I am sorry for asking a very simple question. Please don't vote negative.